# convert all colors of a pdf file to blue using imagemagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

How can I convert all colors no matter what to blue color using imagemagick? or any other simple and fast solution?

I am out of black ink and want to convert a pdf that is in grayscale to only blue color and then print it.
My printer has limited options.

Answer (score 6):

Not certain of what you mean/expect, but try this:

```
convert input.pdf  +level-colors blue, blueResult.pdf
```

It should convert all shades of black to their equivalent shades of blue. So, if you start with this:

[image]

you will get this as a result:

[image]

If your original document is colour, you may need to desaturate first:

```
convert input.pdf -modulate 100,0 +level-colors blue, blueResult.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

```
convert image.pdf -fill blue -colorize 100 image.pdf
```

I am not sure this is what you want. The result will be totally blue everywhere. Do you want something else? You say all colors, but does that include white and black and shades of gray?

If you want every color but white to be blue, then

```
convert image.pdf -fill blue +opaque white image.pdf
```

However, IM is not a good tool to use to go from vector to vector format. IM will rasterize the vector image and then put a vector shell about it.

Comment: I want the white background to stay white

Comment: These commands are great! but how can I produce a 300dpi pdf file for printing?

Comment: @acman123 Try adding `-density 300` near the start of the command line before loading any files.